# How can I find certain rows that match a string efficiently in an html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I show a table in an html page and on a user click I hide certain rows. I hide rows that match a string.
This is how I do it:

```
$("#table").find("tr:not(:has(th))").each(function (index) {
   if($(this).text().indexOf("My String") <0 ) {
       $(this).hide();
}else {
    $(this).show();
    }
});
```

This works fine but I was wondering if there is a smarter/more efficient way than doing a string compare in each row in the table

Comment: Post the code for your table.

Comment: @j08691:How does this matter?It is a normal table

Comment: If you're looking for smart/efficient solutions it would make sense to show the code you're searching through. Or don't. Your choice.

Comment: @j08691:But there is nothing strange about the code.A plaint old html table with a few columns but many rows.I did not think that it matters,only clutter my OP.If you think that it would make a difference I can add it

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($(".table tbody").find("tr"), function () {                              

            if ($(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '').indexOf(searchthis.replace(/\s+/g, '')) == -1)
                $(this).hide();
            else
                $(this).show();});
```

Here searchthis will be text you want to search